# Take sum of rows for every 3 columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have searched high and low and also tried multiple options to solve this but did not get the desired output as mentioned below:

I have dataframe df3 with headers as date and values beteween 0-1 as shown below:

```
df = data.frame(replicate(6,sample(0:1,6,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df) = c("1/1/2018","1/2/2018","1/3/2018","1/4/2018","1/5/2018","1/6/2018")
df2 = data.frame(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))
colnames(df2) = c("CUST_ID")
df3 = cbind(df2,df)
```

[image]

Now I need df4 in which sum of first 3 columns in series will form one column.  This will be repeated in series for rest of the columns dynamically.

df4

[image]

Options I tried:

```
a) rbind.data.frame(apply(matrix(df3, nrow = n - 1), 1,sum))

b) col_list <- list(c("1/1/2018","1/2/2018","1/3/2018"), c("1/4/2018","1/5/2018","1/6/2018"))

lapply(col_list, function(x)sum(df3[,x])) %>% data.frame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to split `df3` every 3 columns using `split.default`. To split the data we generate a sequence using `rep`, then for each dataframe we take `rowSums` and finally `cbind` the result together.

```
cbind(df3[1], sapply(split.default(df3[-1],  
         rep(1:ncol(df3), each = 3, length.out = (ncol(df3) -1))), rowSums))



#  CUST_ID 1 2
#1       A 1 1
#2       B 2 0
#3       C 2 1
#4       D 1 1
#5       E 2 2
#6       F 2 2
```

FYI, the sequence generated from `rep` is

```
rep(1:ncol(df3), each = 3, length.out = (ncol(df3) -1))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

This makes it possible to split every 3 columns.

The results are different because OP used `sample` without `set.seed`.

---

If `rep` seems too long then we can generate the same sequence of columns using `gl`

```
gl(ncol(df3[-1])/3, 3)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
#Levels: 1 2
```

So the final code, would be

```
cbind(df3[1], sapply(split.default(df3[-1], gl(ncol(df3[-1])/3, 3)), rowSums))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `seq` to create index, get the subset of columns within in a `list`, `Reduce` by taking the sum, and create new columns

```
df4 <- df3[1]
df4[paste0('col', c('123', '456'))] <- lapply(seq(2, ncol(df3), by = 3), 
                   function(i) Reduce(`+`, df3[i:min((i+2), ncol(df3))]))
df4
#  CUST_ID col123 col456
#1       A      2      2
#2       B      3      3
#3       C      1      3
#4       D      2      3
#5       E      2      1
#6       F      0      1
```

#### data

```
set.seed(123)
df  <- data.frame(replicate(6,sample(0:1,6,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df) <- c("1/1/2018","1/2/2018","1/3/2018","1/4/2018","1/5/2018","1/6/2018")
df2 <-  data.frame(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))
colnames(df2) = c("CUST_ID")
df3 <- cbind(df2, df)
```